# Must $f$ be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ be a function such that the image of any closed bounded set is closed and bounded. Must $f$ be continuous?

Answer (score 5):

No.

For example take $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$f(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$

$f(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 0$

Comment: Wow, this is a case of two solutions independently and simultaneously being developed if I ever saw one :) I'll delete mine since yours is timestamped earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the image by $f$ of *any* set is closed and bounded, for example because $f(\mathbb R^n)=\{a,b\}$ for some $a\ne b$ in $\mathbb R^m$. Such functions $f$ need not be continuous (example?).

(Once you will have exhibited such a function discontinuous at a point, say, you might try to find one which is discontinuous *everywhere*, since the idea is the same.)

Comment: Nice example @did, but reading your answer I was thinking if one can find a counterexample $f$ which preserves connectedness and compactness.

Comment: If $n=m=1$, try $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$.